# Expected input to be a number but got TRUE/FALSE

Tags: netlogo

I have got this block of code:

```
to catch-rose
  let prey one-of roses-here                    
  if prey != nobody                      
    [
     set energy energy + 1
     set rose_ramasse rose_ramasse + 1
     ask prey [ die ]                        
    ]
end
```

When I launch the simulation, I get the following error message

> ```
> + expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead.
> error while unefeebleue 2 running +
>   called by procedure CATCH-ROSE
>     called by procedure GO
>     called by Button 'go'*
> ```

I've been trying to solve out my problem myself but I can't.  Why it does not want to recognize the second SET command? Why does it think it is true/false statement?

Comment: Are both `energy` and `rose_ramasse` numerical values?  It looks like the `+` operator is complaining that one of its inputs is a `TRUE/FALSE` instead of a number.  As `1` is plainly a number, my guess is that the variable is not.  I get exactly that error if the variable I am adding to is not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you the following:

1. It starts with the operation that failed.  Often this is a procedure name, in this case it is `+`.  So you know that it is one of the inputs to `+` that is failing.
2. It's telling you that one of the inputs to `+` is a `TRUE/FALSE` value.

Now, you've told us that the line it refers to is the second `set` statement.  There are two inputs to the `+` on that line, `rose_ramasse` and `1`

So, your problem is that `rose_ramasse` is a `TRUE/FALSE` (boolean) value.  Without the rest of your code, it's not clear whether `rose_ramasse` is a global variable or not, so it is hard to go any further to help you work out where `rose_ramasse` is being assigned a boolean value.

I can replicate the error message with a simple function like the following:

```
globals [age]

to go
    set age TRUE
    set age age + 1
```

Comment: it was helpful to find the reason ,actualy it was a simple mistake , i did not initialised the rose_ramasse = 0 ,like energy = 5